# Reverse the order of the words in C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

I want to reverse the order of the words (not the characters) in a specific string with constant extra space in linear time?

Comment: You're going to need to write a program to do that.

Comment: You can reverse the letters of each word and then the whole string

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Or tried anything?

Comment: It's not clear if you know the algorithm or need help figuring out the algorithm to use. Can you clarify your question with what you do and don't need help with? If you have an algorithm you want to use, tell us what algorithm that is. If you don't know what algorithm to use, explain to us what difficulty you're having working one out.

Comment: ***Show Code***

Answer (score 3):

First, reverse the whole string (by swapping the first and the last character, towards the middle, etc). This should be enough of a hint to get you started. If not, read on:

Then reverse the order of the characters in each word. Now the characters in each word are in the original order (they were reversed twice overall), but the words are in reverse order (the first word is now at the end, etc.)